# Reset numbering using \enumsentence

Tags: numbering, enumerate, linguistics, lingmacros

I am using **\enumsentence** and **\eenumsentence** for numbering examples. I wonder if I want to reset the counter for an example, what commands are necessary?

For example, I have an example whose counter is (63), but I want it to start with (1). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome! It would be better if you specify in the question the package you are using, not only in the tags.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence macros use a counter called `enums`. You can set this counter to the desired number. Note that you need to set it to the number you want minus one, because the counter is increased at the start of a new sentence.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lingmacros}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{enums}{62}
\enumsentence{This is the first sentence}
\eenumsentence{\item this is a second sentence
\item this is a third sentence}
\setcounter{enums}{0}
\enumsentence{This is the first sentence}
\eenumsentence{\item this is a second sentence
\item this is a third sentence}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly.